# Method of exiting and closing file for both Windows + Linux

Tags: python, file-io

At the moment I'm using this code

```
if __name__=="__main__":
    try:
        main()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        f.close
        print "left!"
```

Is that the best way to do it?  Earlier on in the script a file is being written to and I want to make sure its closed cleanly should the script be terminated.  Any views please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that: `f.close` doesn't actually close the file, you have to call the function: `f.close()`

To answer your question, the best way is using a `with` block. The file will be automatically closed even if an exception is raised:

```
with open('test.txt') as f:
    pass
# Automatically closes file on with block exit
```